# Creating Container Control In WPF

Tags: wpf, controls, containers

I wanted to create a container control which accepts multiple child control in it, something like Grid.

```
  <Controls:DataCaptureForm Background="Wheat" FormTitle="Product" >
        <UserControls:InputField x:Name="ProductName" Caption="Product Name" FieldType="TextInput" />
        <UserControls:InputField x:Name="ProductName1" Caption="Product Name" FieldType="TextInput" />
    </Controls:DataCaptureForm>
```

Here DataCaptureForm is a custom control which is inherited from Panel class.
In XAML, it shows an error

> The property 'content' can only be set once

When I use this DataCaptureForm and add two child controls. Can we create such container control which hold two or more controls in WPF ?

Comment: How is DataCaptureForm implemented?

Comment: Maybe you could jusy use stylized ItemsControl?

Comment: public class DataCaptureForm : Panel
    {
    }

Comment: why can't you use stackpanel, wrappanel

Comment: Or even simple canvas

Comment: Do we need use the stack panel / canvas directly in our XAML or can we create a custom type from stack panel / canvas. My Idea is to have a Custom control for Data Capture form, which has some default template like Header, Footer with Save button. I don't want to repeat this template in every form.

Comment: [How to: Create a Custom Panel Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-custom-panel-element)

Comment: That helps, thanks Clemens